# Should I add useCallback or useMemo to my effect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following tooltip will call the API once the user hovers on a button.
I wonder if I need to work with `useCallback` or `useMemo` to avoid unnecessary API calls? I still struggle to understand when I need one of the two. If it makes sense to add it, how would you do it?

```
const ProfileTooltip = ({ children, userId }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [profileInfo, setProfileInfo] = useState(false);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!open) {
        return;
      }
  
      const fetchProfileInfo = async () => {
        try {
          const { data } = await api.get(`users/${userId}/info/`);
          setProfileInfo(data);
        } catch (e) {
          setProfileInfo(null);
        }
      };
      fetchProfileInfo();
    }, [open, userId]);
  
    const handleOpen = () => {
      setOpen(true);
    };
  
    const handleClose = () => {
      setOpen(false);
    };
  
    const renderTooltip = () => {
      if (!profileInfo) {
        return;
      }
  
      return (
        <>
          <h3 className={classes.profileName}>
            {profileInfo.firstName} {profileInfo.lastName}
          </h3>
          <p className={classes.headline}>{profileInfo.headline}</p>
          <Button size="small" variant="contained" color="primary" fullWidth>
            Message
          </Button>
        </>
      );
    };
  
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Tooltip
          arrow
          classes={{
            tooltip: classes.tooltip,
            arrow: classes.arrow,
            tooltipArrow: classes.tooltipArrow,
            popperArrow: classes.popperArrow,
          }}
          interactive
          placement="top-start"
          onOpen={handleOpen}
          onClose={handleClose}
          title={renderTooltip()}
        >
          {children}
        </Tooltip>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default ProfileTooltip;
```

Comment: useMemo and useCallback are pretty similiar, just use useCallback when dealing with functions, and useMemo with data (objects, arrays, strings etc)

Comment: What you add it to in the provided code snippet? The open/close handlers and/or renderTooltip callback that are passed? `useMemo` and `useCallback` are generally used to make "stable" references to values and functions, and often as a performance optimization. But these can be tricky. If there's not a performance issue then don't prematurely optimize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useCallback` hook is used to memoize callback functions so that they are not re-created every time component re-renders. This is useful when you want to pass a function to a child component and that child component depends on reference equality to avoid unnecessary re-renders.

`useMemo` hook is used to memoize values to avoid doing expensive computations on every render of the component. Function passed to `useMemo` runs during rendering, so any code that has side effects should not be written in this function.

> I wonder if I need to work with useCallback or useMemo to avoid
> unnecessary API calls?

Both these hooks won't help in your case.

Side effects such as API calls belong in `useEffect` hook and to optimize the execution of your side effect, you will need to look at the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook.

You could, however, wrap `handleOpen` and `handleClose` functions in `useCallback` hook. Doing this will prevent re-creating these functions on every render and a memoized function reference will be passed to `Tooltip` component.

You will need to make sure that you get the dependency array of `useCallback` hook right otherwise you will run into bugs that could be hard to debug.

Comment: Hi Yousaf, okay thank you. I think I understood the difference. So basically the way I built it now already makes sense as the API call is handled within the `useEffect`. As handleOpen/Closed only changes the open const. It seems like over-optimization to me at this point?

Comment: Yes, unless there is a performance issue, you don't need to over optimize everything.